# How to check for specific string format in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program that takes in times in the format Hours:Minutes so an example input would be 1:56 or 0:12.

Is there a way to specifically check to make sure the input in that format?Also what are null terminators I can use? I'm use to python so C is really confusing me. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int hour=0, minute=0, total=0;
  while (hour != -1)
  {
    printf ("Enter dive times in the format of HH:MM (hours:minutes), Enter -1 to stop\n");
    scanf("%d:%d",&hour, &minute);
    if ((hour < -1) || (minute < 0))
    {
    printf("Invalid input");
    }
    else
    {
      printf ("total: %d hour: %d minute: %d", total, hour*60, minute);
      total = total + (hour*60) + minute; 
    } 
  } 
    printf("The total is %d The hours is %d The minutes is %d\n",total, (total/60), (total%60) );
    printf("The total divetime is %d:%d", total/60, total%60);
```

Comment: Start with checking return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to specifically check to make sure the input in that format?

1. Read the *line* of user input as a string:

   ```
   char buf[100];
   if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
     Handle_EndOfFile_or_InputError();
   }
   ```
2. Scan the string.  Look for an `int` `:` `int`.  Also scan for additional text the should not be there. (`sentinel`)

   ```
   char sentinel;
   if (sscanf(buf, "%d :%d %c", hour, minute, &sentinel) != 2) {
     Handle_InputIsNot2int();
   }
   ```
3. Check range

   ```
   #define HOUR_MIN 0
   #define HOUR_MAX 23
   #define MINUTE_MIN 0
   #define MINUTE_MAX 59
   if (hour<HOUR_MIN || hour>HOUR_MAX || minute<MINUTE_MIN || minute>MINUTE_MAX) {
     Handle_InputOutOfRange();
   }
   ```
4. O Happy day!  Use `hour,minute` as needed,

   ```
   total += (hour*60) + minute;
   ```

Comment: Need checking  input with `-1` between 1. and 2. ? `hour < 1 || hour > 12` --> `hour < 0 || hour > 23` or `hour < 0` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Replaced magic numbers with macros to allow OP to customize easily as needed.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` [returns an error](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) if the input was not formatted like the format string (but remember that it allows anything at all to follow the input (like "3:5HELLO"), leaving it for the next read).

As for [null terminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), there's nothing in this code that makes you have to think about them.

Answer (score 1):

this code :

```
if ((hour < -1) || (minute < 0))
    printf("Invalid input");
```

to :

```
if((hour < -1) || (hour > 12) || (minute < 0) || (minute > 60))
    printf("Invalid input");
```

i think null terminators mean is The string must be NULL at the end.

"this is string **\0**".

Comment: "NULL" is best used to describe the _null pointer constant_ `NULL` and its use with pointers.  C specifies that strings end with a _null character_ (`'\0'`).